# Sign Up Form Error: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

So this is my first attempt kind of just going without tutorial direction on building a site on RoR. Running into some trouble setting up my email signup form. I think there is an issue with how my model is setup or connected but not too sure. Getting "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" as the error".

signup.rb

```
class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :email

    def change
        create_tabe :quotes do |t|

            t.string :email
        end
    end

end
```

signups_controller.rb

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @signup = Signup.new
    end

    def create
        @signup = Signup.new(secure_params)
        if @signup.valid?
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render :new
    end

    private

    def secure_params
        params.require(:signup).permit(:email)
    end

end
```

simple form section of the view

```
<%= simple_form_for @signup do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.submit 'Signup', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#index'
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  get '/tour' => 'pages#tour'
  get '/music' => 'pages#music'

  resources :signups, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: where are you getting this error? And as I notice why is your migration code in the model?

Comment: Oh sorry, that might be helpful: 

<%= simple_form_for @signup do |f| %>

is the line the error is one when trying to visit localhost:3000

Comment: Do you know about migrations and model? As you have written the code for migration in model.

Comment: Yes, I was just referencing two different code bases I had from previous tutorials trying to pull what I needed to do from both and I think that is why I don't have the model set up. Ran db:migrate but still got the error.

Comment: Just spotted an error in the model - missing an l in table. I corrected that, did rake db:rollback and rake db:migrate but still running into the error.

Comment: Actually the code written in your model should go in migration. Just remove that code and then look what error you are getting. I think the `@signup` is a problem in the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= simple_form_for @signup do |f| %> 
to 


<%= simple_form_for :signup  do |f| %>
```

For now it will not throw any error because of symbol `:signup` but for submit the form you need the `action` `attributes` for that you can use like `url: { action: "create" }` [click for more detail](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Hope this help you.

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.