# No route matches [POST] "/" - trying to set up mailing list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, mailchimp

I feel like I am missing something simple here. I set up a MailChimp mailing list and I am trying to get the sign up button to work but getting an error for the submission. I have it routed back to the root in the create method in the controller but it isn't working.

signup.rb

```
class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i

    def subscribe
        mailchimp = Gibbon::API.new
        result = mailchimp.lists.subscribe({
        :id => ENV['MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID'],
        :email => {:email => self.email},
        :double_optin => false,
        :update_existing => true,
        :send_welcome => true
        })
        Rails.logger.info("Subscribed #{self.email} to MailChimp") if result
    end

end
```

signups_controller.rb

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @signup = Signup.new
    end

    def create
        @signup = Signup.new(secure_params)
        if @signup.valid?
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    private

    def secure_params
        params.require(:signup).permit(:email)
    end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#index'
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  get '/tour' => 'pages#tour'
  get '/music' => 'pages#music'

  resources :signups, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

What can I put in routes.rb to get this to post? Here is my rake routes output...

```
    Prefix Verb URI Pattern            Controller#Action
      root GET  /                      pages#index
     about GET  /about(.:format)       pages#about
      tour GET  /tour(.:format)        pages#tour
     music GET  /music(.:format)       pages#music
   signups POST /signups(.:format)     signups#create
new_signup GET  /signups/new(.:format) signups#new
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly do you get that error? Can you show us the view form?

Comment: Also, you're neither saving the Signup nor calling ``#subscribe`` on it, BTW.

Comment: <br />
<%= simple_form_for :signup do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :email, label: false, :placeholder => 'cantwaittoseeyou@ournextshow.com' %>
 <br />
     <%= f.submit 'Sign Up', :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
   <% end %>
   <br>

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<%= simple_form_for :signup do |f| %>
```

for

```
<%= simple_form_for @signup do |f| %>
```

and you'll route to `SignupsController#create`.

Apart from that, you need to call `Signup#subscribe` anywhere in your code for the whole form to work. Probably you want to save the Signup to the database as well. I suggest this change in the controller:

```
def create
    @signup = Signup.new(secure_params)
    if @signup.save && @signup.subscribe 
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Ooops!'
      render :new
    end
end
```

and remember to return `true` from `Signup#subscribe` if the `result` was successful.

Comment: That resulted in this error from before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363650/sign-up-form-error-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilclassclass